# How to use ipa-getcert with file injections

Tags: linux, ipa, ca

I am trying to figure out the best solution for below.

```
[user]:~>BLAH=$"cat text.txt"
[user]:~>ipa-getcert stop-tracking -i $BLAH
```

the `text.txt` document hosts the Request ID of a cert.

However, its not actually putting the info in the command. Is there an IPA command that can find and replace the old certs with out manual Request ID entries?

Or is there another way to inject the ID that is inside the text.txt?

Comment: try `BLAT=$(< file)`. (note the `$(...)`). Good luck.

Comment: Error : no Match for the argument. This is telling me that it can't parse out what $BLAH is when next to the ipa command.

Comment: also doesn't () just identify the inserted text as a command and "" identifies the internal text as just text? i'm just trying to add in the text information from the file to the command as a substitution.

Comment: yes, if you only want the text `"cat text.tst` assigned to your varialbe BLAH, then use dbl-quotes. As I'm not familiar with ipa-getcert, I assumed that `$BLAH` was variable meant to indicate what `getcert` was to target for its' search. If you want the value stored in `text.tst`, then `var=$(cat text.tst)` will populate `$var` with that value, same with `$(< text.tst)`. Can't really be sure what you're trying to do here, so try to show all steps and outputs in the body of your Q. Also indicate the expected result. Do you know about `set -x`, this will show the values of all variables subd'

Comment: sed command worked well